# Adding the provisioning file to Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode4, code-signing, ios-provisioning

Under Build -> Code Signing Identity -> Distribution (this is a duplicate of Release, renamed) I selected Any IOS SDK and it wont let me select my provisioning file that I downloaded from apple:

[image]

I have the provisioning file in my downloads folder. is there some where I should be putting it so that xcode sees it when I try and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop the provisioning on xcode icon.

Or look this tutorial for use provisioning with xcode :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html